# Belt Drive Shaft - What Profile is This?

Tags: gears, mechanisms, machining, aluminum, actuator

I'm trying to source a similar extruded aluminum round profile, that I can attach a belt to, as in the pic below. The shaft will turn and pull on that belt.

I looked at the 80-20 extrusions and similar profiles but didn't see anything quite like this.

[image: round extruded drive shaft]

Comment: So perhaps they have it made for them, and it is not on public sale. Design and make an equivalent.

Comment: some of these have a circular profile ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=custom+aluminium+extrusions&iax=images&ia=images